# Android 5.0 Back icon parent activity

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm migrating my projects to new Material design / Android 5.0 Lollipop now.
In previous Android versions it was easy to create Activity with back ActionBar button (arrow) using `android:parentActivityName` in AndroidManifest.xml. But it seems that in doesn't work any more on new API with support libraries `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+`.

Below is my code and screenshots from previous and updated to Lollipop support example project:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.serge.androidprobe.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="Activity1:Parent" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="org.serge.androidprobe.app.SecondActivity"
                android:parentActivityName="org.serge.androidprobe.app.MainActivity"
                android:label="Activity2" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Before migration to Lollipop:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {/**/ }

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {/**/ }

<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

[image]

**After migration to Lollipop:**

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity {/**/ }

public class SecondActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity {/**/ }

<resources>
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
</resources>
```

[image]

Note: before migration to Lollipop I haven't used support/appcompat libs at all.

How to make back arrow visible & clickable on the top-left corner using new v21 of support/appcompat libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In yours `onCreate` try calling

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

You then handle the click by checking `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: Damn, it was so easy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help, I went though the same process 3 weeks go :) In general, you want to refactor most of your calls from "native" to "support", e.g. instead of getFragmentManager you call getSupportFragmentManager etc.